# Mysqli SELECT JOINS multiple WHERES

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a problem with multiple `where`s in a consult to database mysqli. I don't know how to make it. I'm reading about JOINS for multiple consults, but I don't know it very well, and it still doesn't work. This is my code:

```
$status = mysqli_escape_string($con, $_POST['status']);
$type = mysqli_escape_string($con, $_POST['type']);
$beds = mysqli_escape_string($con, $_POST['beds']);
$baths = mysqli_escape_string($con, $_POST['baths']);
$query = "SELECT * FROM properties WHERE beds LIKE '%".$beds."%' OR baths LIKE '%".$baths."%' " ;
```

I need to obtain all results that have beds, baths, status, types, etc, but it does not work with the actual SELECT. I already made some tries with JOINS, but that did not work the way I expected. This function gives all the results but not filtered. Thank you for any help!

EDIT:

This is all my code, my form

```
<form action="" id="amenities-form" name="amenities-form" data-name="Amenities Form" class="top-search-form-left" method="POST">
      <select id="status" name="status" data-name="status" class="select-search-form w-select">
        <option value="sale">For Sale</option>
        <option value="rent">For Rent</option>
      </select>
      <select id="type" name="type" data-name="type" class="select-search-form w-select">
        <option value="">Type of property</option>
        <option value="condo">Condo</option>
        <option value="house">House</option>
        <option value="commercial">Commercial</option>
        <option value="lot">Lot</option>
        <option value="villa">Villa</option>
        <option value="business">Business</option>
        <option value="fractional">Fractional</option>
        <option value="boat">Boat</option>
      </select>
      <input type="text" class="input-search-form w-input" maxlength="256" name="beds" data-name="beds" placeholder="Beds" id="beds">
      <input type="text" class="input-search-form w-input" maxlength="256" name="baths" data-name="baths" placeholder="Baths" id="baths">
      <input type="submit" value="Go" class="btn-search-left w-button">
  </form>
  <form action="" id="search-form" name="search-form" data-name="Search Form" class="top-search-form-right" method="POST">
    <input type="text" class="input-search-form w-input" maxlength="256" name="search" data-name="search" placeholder="Search..." id="search-word">
    <input type="submit" value="Lupa" class="btn-search-right w-button">
  </form>
```

This is my code of php

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
$con = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  printf("Falló la conexión failed: %s\n", $con->connect_error);
  exit();
}
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
  $search = mysqli_escape_string($con, $_POST['search']);
  $query = "SELECT * FROM properties WHERE title LIKE '%".$search."%'" ;
}else{
  $status = mysqli_escape_string($con, $_POST['status']);
  $type = mysqli_escape_string($con, $_POST['type']);
  $beds = mysqli_escape_string($con, $_POST['beds']);
  $baths = mysqli_escape_string($con, $_POST['baths']);
  $query = "SELECT * FROM properties WHERE beds LIKE '%".$beds."%' OR baths LIKE '%".$baths."%' " ;
}

$res = $con->query($query);

if (!$res) {
  trigger_error('Invalid query: ' . $con->error);
}

if ($res->num_rows) {
  while ($row = $res->fetch_object()) {
    //$status_name = $con->query("SELECT * FROM status WHERE id = {$row->status_id}");
    //$status_name = $status_name->fetch_object();
    //echo "{$row->title} ({$status_name->title})<br>";
    echo "{$row->title} ({$row->status_id})<br>";
  }
}else{
  echo "No results";
}

$res->free();

$con->close();
}else{
  echo 'No results';
}
```

I will try some suggest you did

Comment: Did you try `AND` in place of the `OR` ? Also ... prepared statements will do some safeguarding after you figure out your query. I dont know what you would `JOIN` if you only have one table `properties`.

Comment: well maybe i am doing bad, i have only one table properties but i give many values in $_POST and i want consult all properties WHERE beds LIKE %$beds% OR baths LIKE %baths% maybe is not with JOIN but still not make the filter always give me all the properties

Comment: See about prepared and bound queries

Comment: As @IncredibleHat said, you probably need to use `AND`. If that is not the case, you will need to dynamically construct the query based on the parameters given'; if `$baths` or `$beds` are empty, you will get all rows (because `[anything other than null] LIKE '%%'` is always true). _I'm not really sure `LIKE` is appropriate anyway; those fields sound like they should be numeric values._

Comment: Right @Uueerdo I'm thinking he may be headed down a fully dynamic built query with all the possible filters :/

Comment: We could make all sorts of comments based on guesswork, or you could **add some sample data and the expected result** so we can propose a real solution. Please add data and show us what the result should look like, from that we should be able to propose a solution. [See MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [Why should I provide a MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Perhaps you can try something like this: `SELECT * FROM properties WHERE beds is not null AND beds != '' AND beds LIKE '%".$beds."%' AND baths is not null AND baths != '' AND baths LIKE '%".$baths."%';` This will not include rows that don't have values for `beds` and `baths`.

Comment: See edit i add all my code and the form

Comment: I already fixed with your help

`$query = "
        SELECT pr.* FROM properties as pr 
          INNER JOIN status as st
            ON pr.status_id = st.id
          INNER JOIN types as ty
            ON pr.type_id = ty.id
          WHERE st.title LIKE '%".$status."'
            AND pr.beds LIKE '%".$beds."' 
            AND pr.baths LIKE '%".$baths."'
            AND ty.title LIKE '%".$type."'
      ";`

thanks xD